# NSFetchedResultsController, Core data and Threading

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hello fellow overflowers

I have a hard time figuring out how to fetch NSManagedObjects in a background thread and then show the results via a NSFetchedResultsController.

This is my code so far:

```
       _theManagedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedInstance] mainManagedObjectContext]; 

   __block NSMutableArray *objectsIDs;

    [[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ret" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];

        NSArray *results =  [[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        for (Ret *ret in results) {
            NSManagedObjectID *moID = [ret objectID];

            [objectsIDs addObject:moID]; 

            NSLog(@"%@", objectsIDs); 
        }

        [[[DataManager sharedInstance] mainManagedObjectContext ] performBlock:^{

            [self loadDishesWithObjectIDs:objectsIDs]; 

        }];



    }];
```

First I fetch all the objects in a background thread and then transfering the NSMangedObjectIDs to the main thread.

In my "loadDishes" method:

```
- (void)loadDishesWithObjectIDs:(NSArray *)objectsIDs {

     /*
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"dishes"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:**???**? managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"dishes"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;




    NSError *error = nil;


    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch Failed");

    }


    NSArray *theDishes = _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;*/



}
```

How would I manage to show the objects with NSFetchResultscontroller by the ObjectIDs which is fetched from the background thread ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a fetch request that looks something like this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ret" 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] mainManagedObjectContext]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", objectIDs];
```